# How to join dataframe with another containing scalar value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Trying to join two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'foo': ['abc','def','jkl','mno','pqr']}) 
d = {1:100, 2:200, 3:300, 4:400, 5:500}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()))
df1.join(df2)
```

As a result I get:

```
    id  foo 0   1
------------------
0   1   abc 1   100
1   2   def 2   200
2   3   jkl 3   300
3   4   mno 4   400
4   5   pqr 5   500
```

How instead get this:

```
    id  foo     cnt
------------------
0   1   abc     100
1   2   def     200
2   3   jkl     300
3   4   mno     400
4   5   pqr     500
```

Comment: What's the logic? You want a simple horizontal concatenation excluding your `0` clumn? Or you want to merge these data frames, matching them respective on `id` and `0` ?

Comment: rename `df2` , then merge: `df2.columns=['id','cnt']`
`df1.merge(df2,on='id')` ? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: `df1['cnt'] = df2[1]`

Comment: You want:`df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={0:'id', 1:'cnt'}), on='id')`. The reason you are also getting the first column of `df2` is because  `join` is on the indices.

Comment: `df1.set_index('id').join(df2.set_index(0))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename `df2` and `merge` not `join`

`df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={0: 'id', 1: 'cnt'}), on='id')`

```
   id  foo  cnt
0   1  abc  100
1   2  def  200
2   3  jkl  300
3   4  mno  400
4   5  pqr  500
```